# How to calculate a grid based on 4 curved edges?

Tags: grid, 2d, interpolation, point, mesh

How can I calculate the points on a 2D grid where the the edges are 4 curved beziers?

(see picture):

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/f4c4f64d98.gif](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/f4c4f64d98.gif)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a parametric representation to map points from a unit square with corners [1, 1], [-1, 1], [-1, -1], [1, -1] onto the Bezier quad by transforming from one coordinate system to the other by calculating the Jacobean from one to the other.

[This article](http://www.waset.org/journals/waset/v25/v25-54.pdf) shows you how.  It's a common thing to do in finite element analysis, because most modern elements are expressed in terms of shape functions in a parametric space.  You have to transform from the parametric to element coordinates using the techniques shown in that article.